# Problem when change icon in android studio

Tags: java, android

When I change the icon, it only shows up in the debug version, but in the release version, it doesn't change the icon. How to fix it ? Thanks.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDpVu.png)

Comment: include manifest and build.gradle code

Comment: I have fixed it. I am confused between choosing debug and release folder

Comment: choose release and see how it goes.